# Strange bug from Receiver with Sqlite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a bug on my receiver, but I can't find where it comes from!
In my application the user can program reminders (notifications), x day to x time. So I have a broadcast receiver which is responsible for programming these notifications each time the phone is restarted.
Error : `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException`

Here is the code:

DATABASEHANDLER

```
public List<ReminderClass> getAllReminders() {
    List<ReminderClass> reminderList = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_REMINDERS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ReminderClass reminderClass = new ReminderClass();
                reminderClass.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_REMINDERS_ID)));
                reminderClass.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_REMINDERS_name)));
                reminderClass.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_REMINDERS_desc2)));
                reminderClass.setJours(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_REMINDERS_jours)));
                reminderClass.setHeure(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_REMINDERS_heure)));
                reminderClass.setMinute(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_REMINDERS_minute)));
                reminderClass.setEmptyZoneInt(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_REMINDERS_emptyZoneInt)));
                reminderClass.setEmptyZoneStr(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_REMINDERS_emptyZoneStr)));
                reminderClass.setShowJours(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_REMINDERS_show)));
                reminderClass.setNotifId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_REMINDERS_notifId)));
                reminderList.add(reminderClass);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return reminderList;
}
```

RECEIVER

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    List<ReminderClass> remindersList = App.DB().getAllReminders();

    if (remindersList != null && !remindersList.isEmpty()) {
        for (ReminderClass reminderClass : remindersList) {
            int id = reminderClass.getNotifId();
            Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
            calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, reminderClass.getHeure());
            calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, reminderClass.getMinute());
            calender.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            Intent alarmReceiver = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver2.class);
            alarmReceiver.putExtra("reminderId", reminderClass.getId());
            alarmReceiver.putExtra("NotificationId", id);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, alarmReceiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calender.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            setNotification(context, id);
        }
    }
}

private void setNotification(Context context, int id) {
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calender.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiverHabit.class);
    intent.putExtra("NotificationId", id);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calender.getTimeInMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

Manifest
       
                
                    
                    
                
            
EDIT : ERROR MESSAGE FROM DEV CONSOLE :

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement (Native Method)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement (SQLiteConnection.java:1229)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare (SQLiteConnection.java:703)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare (SQLiteSession.java:588)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init> (SQLiteProgram.java:59)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init> (SQLiteQuery.java:37)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query (SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory (SQLiteDatabase.java:1865)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery (SQLiteDatabase.java:1804)
  at com.com.treasureapp.WorkApp.DatabaseHandler.getAllReminders (DatabaseHandler.java:340)
  at com.com.treasureapp.Receiver.AlarmReceiverHabit.onReceive (AlarmReceiverHabit.java:20)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3614)
```

Comment: Do you have the full error message for us?

Comment: I've make an edit :)

Comment: Ok I will try this solution ty :)

Comment: Not ok, i will search another solution... ^^

Comment: Did you use the debugger to find out a what point it breaks? If so, can you tell me?

Comment: It works very well for me, only a few users have a bug there. I really don't understand :/

Comment: Then you should find out what specialities these users have

Comment: Yes ty Lucadmin

Comment: I am dealing with the very same problem. Did you managed to find out what was the culprit? Thanks in advance...

Comment: No sorry, If you find it can you give me the solution ?... :(